# Yesod return whole Entity after insert?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

Basically right now I run `fbId <- runDB $ insert myNewFooBar` and I get back a `Key FooBar`. Is there any way to return the value of the whole `FooBar` directly from an insert without running a separate query of `runDB $ get404 fbId` after?

Comment: Isn't `myNewFooBar` already the value of the whole `FooBar`?

Comment: It wouldn't have an ID at that point though would it?

Comment: OK so that in combination with @bergey's suggestion fixes everything. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just build the `Entity` Haskell-side: `Entity fbId myNewFooBar`.

Answer (score 1):

Another, shorter option is to use [`insertEntity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:insertEntity), which returns an entity instead of a record. Under the hood this function calls `insert` and builds an entity from the supplied record and the returned key (no additional DB queries).

```
insertedFooBar <- runDB $ insertEntity myNewFooBar
```